# Free vehicle service manuals

Tags: service-manual

i work as a mechanic in a plant machinery/ van and truck rental place.

They have very few service manuals there. What are the chances i can get free manuals from the likes of Ford, and construction equipment manufacturers etc.

Considering we buy alot of equipment from them etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Then you ask for the workshop manual as part of the sale.

No salesman will let a sale, and their commission, fall through for the price of a manual.

But if you wait until after, then you pay...

Answer (score -1):

I purchased 2 service manuals from https://www.emanualonline.com/  for a Mazda 3 and ford e450 Not sure if it’s a “proper” way of obtaining a manual but it worked for me. It’s not free but affordable.